# For loop inside getjson - Framework7/Jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html-framework-7

I have a for loop inside a getjson call, but the loop not work…

```
var woeid = '455827';
    var yql = encodeURIComponent('select * from weather.forecast where woeid = "' + woeid + '"and u="c"')
        $$.getJSON('https://query.yahooapis.com/v1/public/yql?q='+ yql + '&format=json', function (data) {

        var forecast = data.query.results.channel.item.forecast;

        //Forecast
        for(var i=0;i<=forecast.length;i++){
        //Get
        code = data.query.results.channel.item.forecast[i].code;
        data = data.query.results.channel.item.forecast[i].date;
        weekday = data.query.results.channel.item.forecast[i].day;
        max = data.query.results.channel.item.forecast[i].high;
        min = data.query.results.channel.item.forecast[i].low;
        console.log(max);
        }
        });},3000)
```

The loop not work and console.log show nothing… What's wrong?

Thanks

Comment: Show us the YQL query so we can test it, and see the returned data

Comment: Post updated with YQL query

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/b7ju0oma/ <- your loop goes one step further than there are items in the array due to the use of `<=` instead of just `<`, and you have some quote issues and you're not using the `forecast` variable, otherwise seems fine

Comment: I'll use them inside the loop, inserting content with $$(.class).html(variable), but i'm testing with a simple console.log first...

Comment: Adeneo, Quote issues?

Comment: Yes, look at your code and the colors, especially `‘&format=json’` and see how those aren't really quotes.

Comment: Oh, it's wrong only in copy+paste proccess... In my code, is ok, rs

Comment: Then it works, you've seen the fiddle above etc.

Answer (score 0):

Solved: I change my code to this:

Rather than

```
var forecast = data.query.results.channel.item.forecast;
for(var i=0;i<=forecast.length;i++){
        //Get
        code = data.query.results.channel.item.forecast[i].code;
        data = data.query.results.channel.item.forecast[i].date;
        weekday = data.query.results.channel.item.forecast[i].day;
        max = data.query.results.channel.item.forecast[i].high;
        min = data.query.results.channel.item.forecast[i].low;
}
```

I did

```
var forecast = data.query.results.channel.item.forecast;
for(var i=0;i<=forecast.length;i++){
            //Pega      
            code = forecast[i].code;
            data = forecast[i].date;
            weekday = forecast[i].day;
            max = forecast[i].high;
            min = forecast[i].low;
}
```

Although I believe that the first code should work, the second code works for me like a charm

Thank you all :)